# Not sure why my JavaFX GUI won't load?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to execute this code. It's a program that just lets the user enter the sum of two numbers. The two numbers are randomly chosen and theres a get method in another class that retrieves them. I tried to assign that method to the questionField label, but i keep getting a error when i try to run and compile. Can someone help me out and tell me what im doing wrong?

```
public class Assignment5 extends Application {

    // TODO: Instance Variables for View Components and Model
    private MathGame math1;
    private TextField answerField;
    private Label questionField;
    private Label answerRight;
    private Label answerWrong;

    // TODO: Private Event Handlers and Helper Methods
    private void mathHandler(ActionEvent e) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText());
        math1.verify();
    }


    /**
     * This is where you create your components and the model and add event
     * handlers.
     *
     * @param stage The main stage
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 225); // set the size here
        stage.setTitle("Assignment5"); // set the window title here
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // TODO: Add your GUI-building code here

        // 1. Create the model
        math1 = new MathGame();
        // 2. Create the GUI components
        answerField = new TextField("");
        Button input = new Button("OK");
        questionField = new Label("");
        answerRight = new Label("Test");
        answerWrong = new Label("Test");

        // 3. Add components to the root
        root.getChildren().add(answerWrong);
        root.getChildren().add(answerRight);
        root.getChildren().add(questionField);
        root.getChildren().add(answerField);
        root.getChildren().add(input);
        //root.getChildren().add(input);

        // 4. Configure the components (colors, fonts, size, location)
        questionField.setLayoutY(100);
        questionField.setLayoutX(30);
        answerField.setLayoutX(100);
        answerField.setLayoutY(100);
        answerField.setPrefWidth(40);
        answerField.setPrefHeight(20);
        input.setLayoutX(160);
        input.setLayoutY(100);
        answerRight.setLayoutY(140);
        answerWrong.setLayoutY(165);

        // 5. Add Event Handlers and do final setup
        // 6. Show the stage
        stage.show();

    }

    /**
     * Make no changes here.
     *
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and this is the error message i get when i run it

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class Assignment5.Assignment5
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$160(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: Assignment5.MathGame
    at Assignment5.Assignment5.<init>(Assignment5.java:18)
    ... 13 more
Exception running application Assignment5.Assignment5
C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: It would help if you added the error message to your post.

Comment: @Marv yeah sorry, just added it now.

Comment: What line is line 18?

Comment: I am guessing you got errors in `MathGame` class.

Comment: Can you post all `MathGame` class code ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Netbeans IDE:

> C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53

And if you read your exception carefully you will find a `Runtime Exception`that said : `Unable to construct Application instance: class Assignment5.Assignment5`,and netbeans allows you to run the code even if certain classes are not compilable.According to [Nick Fortescue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386076/uncompilable-source-code-runtimeexception-in-netbeans)  and [Viacheslav Vedenin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662679/uncompilable-source-code-erroneous-tree-type-error-and-cannot-find-symbol-erro) answsers.

Because you did not post all code ,So i guess , It was the packaging issue.

So Try do this :

1-Clean and build your project again.

2- try to uncheck "Compile on save" setting in the project properties (Build -> Compiling).

I hope that is helpful for you.